# Empty frame rendering on migration of Swing app to Java 8

Tags: java, swing, java-8, migration

I recently decided to upgrade an old Swing application from Java 1.6 to 1.8.  Unfortunately, when I build and launch the application under Java 8 the window appears and is empty.  If I build and launch under Java 7 or 6 the content displays as expected.  Here is a sample code that reproduced my problem:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class SwingRenderingIssue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
           SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                      frame.setTitle("hello world");
                      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                      panel.add(new JButton("hello again"));
                      frame.setContentPane(panel);
                      frame.pack();
                      frame.setVisible(true);
                  }
           });
        }
}
```

The Java 8 version I have is jdk-8u181-linux-x64.

Comment: I can't reproduce. Have you tried this with Java 9 or 10?

Comment: I also tried using jdk1.8.0_121 on windows and it is working fine. Is this issue happening on Linux only ?

Comment: Yes, linux only.

Comment: I tried Java 10 and everything rendered properly.  Using Java 10 is an acceptable solution for me so that's that I guess.